# sum of unique values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below array `$billitems_taxes`

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tax_name] => A
        [tax_value] => 12
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [tax_name] => A
        [tax_value] => 8
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [tax_name] => B
        [tax_value] => 12
    )
```

and I want output as below, find two common `tax_name` and do some of same and then create a new array.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tax_name] => A
        [tax_value] => 20
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [tax_name] => B
        [tax_value] => 12
    )
```

I tried with below code, but it did not return a correct array.

```
    $return_array = [];
    foreach($billitems_taxes as $b)
    {
        $return_array['tax_name'] = $b->tax_name;
        $return_array['tax_value'] +=  $b->tax_value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have an array of arrays, not objects.

Then your loop needs to know if it has already seen a this tax name which will already be in the new array to check that I used `array_key_exists()`

```
$return_array = [];
foreach($billitems_taxes as $b)
{
    if ( array_key_exists($b['tax_name'], $return_array) ) {
        $return_array[$b['tax_name']]['tax_value'] += $b['tax_value'];
    } else {
        $return_array[$b['tax_name']] = $b;
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
Array(
    [A] => Array
        ([id] => 1
         [tax_name] => A
         [tax_value] => 20
        )

    [B] => Array
        ([id] => 3
         [tax_name] => B
         [tax_value] => 12
        )
)
```

And if its important for the array to be numerically indexed just add

```
$return_array = array_values($return_array);
```

after the end of the loop

Comment: I tried it, but didn't output required array, it output this, ```Array ( [tax_name] => Array ( [tax_name] => B [tax_value] => 12 ) )```

Comment: SORRY, I missed out the `$b` bit, now it works

Answer (score 0):

You must group by 'tax_name' and must sum 'tax_value'.

```
$billitems_taxes = [
  ['id' => 1, 'tax_name' => 'A', 'tax_value' => 12],
  ['id' => 2, 'tax_name' => 'A', 'tax_value' => 8],  
  ['id' => 3, 'tax_name' => 'B', 'tax_value' => 12]
];

$result = [];
foreach($billitems_taxes as $row){
  $groupKey = $row['tax_name'];
  if(array_key_exists($groupKey,$result)){
    $result[$groupKey]['tax_value'] += $row['tax_value'];
  } else {
    $result[$groupKey] = $row;
  }
}
$result = array_values($result);

echo '<pre>';
var_export($result);

/*
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'tax_name' => 'A',
    'tax_value' => 20,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'tax_name' => 'B',
    'tax_value' => 12,
  ),
) 
*/
```

The solution  with the external class [tableArray](https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray) is very simple.  The result is the same.

```
$result = tableArray::create($billitems_taxes)
  ->filterGroupAggregate(['tax_value' => 'SUM'],['tax_name'])
  ->fetchAll()
;
```